# How to send browser notification to specific users / browsers?

Tags: javascript, notifications

I want to send browser notifications on different events to the associated users browsers.

Comment: Is the notification for all users ? or specific notification for a specific user?

Comment: I have already defined in the title that i want to send to specific user.

Answer (score 0):

then go end use notification API.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/notification